# I need a UI Framework compatible with Spring MVC

Tags: jquery, jsp, spring-mvc, user-interface, jsp-tags

I have a Spring Project, where I display my data using JSP. What i hate about it; backend and request handling works like a charm with Spring Data & Spring MVC etc. But on the frontend I must handle everything by myself. I still have to write lot of JSP code, just to display a table for example.

I want to have simple components (like datepicker, table etc.) which are also easy to combine with Spring MVC functionalities, and also with Ajax capability.

JSF has lot of cool stuff like Primefaces. Is there any UI Framework out there, which we can easily use with MVC? Maybe a JSP Tag library?

Comment: You may have a look at [the article](http://blog.zkoss.org/index.php/2015/11/17/rich-web-application-with-spring-mvc-crud-demo/), it used Spring MVC controller to communicate with ZK UI components. (in Java code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what i gather you want something simple and effective for the view layer of the Spring MVC.

I strongly recommend utilising Thymeleaf [www.thymeleaf.org](http://www.thymeleaf.org). Its very robust and flexible.
It works well with ajax, css and other front end widgets/frameworks including angularjs.

Check it out and give it a go, you will be suprised how quick and effective your front UI development becomes.

Hope this helps.